# python pyscopg2 unable to select data from AWS redshift

Tags: python, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I have a postgres database on AWS redshift. Currently I use Python Pyscopg2 to interact with the database. I find that I can run:

```
curosr.execute("INSERT INTO datatype VALUES (%s, %s)", ("humidity", "some description"))
connect.commit()
```

but when I do:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM datatype"):
    print(row)
```

what ever I do, it always returns me None Type. **Anyone can give me advice that what is the correct way to interact with redshift postgres?**

Thank you

As required, here's the **whole code**

```
##encoding=utf8

from __future__ import print_function
import psycopg2

def connect():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host = "wbh1.cqdmrqjbi4nz.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com",
                            port = 5439,
                            dbname = "dbname",
                            user = "user",
                            password = "password")
    c = conn.cursor()
    return conn, c

conn, c = connect()

c.execute("INSERT INTO table netatmo VALUES (%s, %s)", (1, 10.5))
conn.commit() # this works, and I can see the data in other db client software

for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM netatmo").fetchall(): # this not working
    print(row) # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed "fetchall()",
when updating - you don't need it, but when selecting - you have to fetch the results
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html

your code should look like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM datatype;")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Comment: No it's not the reason, I tried fechall fechone, the curosr always returns Null, even the SQL cmd gives me plenty of records in other database client software

Comment: I assume "c.execute" returns None, so when you try to run "c.execute().fetchall() - it tries to find attribute fetchall on None, you should first run "cursor.execute" then "cursor.fetchall"

Comment: from the docs:    execute(operation[, parameters])
Prepare and execute a database operation (query or command).

Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation. Variables are specified either with positional (%s) or named (%(name)s) placeholders. See Passing parameters to SQL queries.

The method returns None. If a query was executed, the returned values can be retrieved using fetch*() methods.

Comment: THankyou I thought it like sqlite3, can automatically return c.execute() as a row generator.